# EC2 cannot access S3 object via IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I created an IAM role as follows and attached to my EC2 instance:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also added bucket policy for my S3 bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<my-aws-account-id>:role/Get-Pic"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Options of Block public access of S3 are:

- [on] Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)
- [on] Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)
- [off] Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies
- [off] Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies

But I still cannot access my S3 from EC2:

```
$ curl https://<my-bucket>.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Instagram.png
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>2006E789486C0744</RequestId><HostId>DVldRN7BgUXvKvXElPYTVGd7mgAsoPEJkH9D/mlrr4Vv5FNZdr0DLbKTFkGu9ZuCo45yPq+i2rU=</HostId></Error>
```

Is there anything I should do?

Comment: Using `curl` you are accessing the s3 as a public website. IAM role on ec2 has nothing to do with that. Your bucket policy does not allow public access, thus you fail.

Comment: On EC2 instance you should be using `aws` cli (or sdk) to access the objects in your bucket, `aws s3 cp s3://......`, not `curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails is that you are using `curl` to access objects as if they were publicly accessible. But your bucket policy does not allow for public read access. The correct policy [should be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html#bucket-policy-static-site):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if you don't want your objects to be publicly accessible, on your instance you should be using AWS CLI to get objects, e.g. [aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html), or SDK, e.g. [boto3's get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object).

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually writing a website which will be using pictures in my S3 bucket. I guess that requires public access too. I thought where is a way that allows an EC2 instance which having the IAM role can access a private S3 bucket...

Comment: Off course there are ways of not making your object public to do it. One one is for your instance to generate pre-signed urls for s3 object you want to put on your website. Other is through accessing your object through cloudfront. Or you can just make only specific objects in your bucket public, e.g. based on prefixes or tags.